# Regular expression R22.5 and R22

Tags: php, regex, drupal, pcre

Need little help!

I have stroke - "R22.5 and R22"

And i need find only R22 word.

I try this: "\bR\d{2,2}\b" but do nothing, because this regular expression return me two variants (R22 and R22)

How to make a regular expression seen only R22, without the fractional part(.xx)?

Thanks!

Comment: Which `R22` do you need? The one at the end, or at the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion to check if a dot and a digit don't follow:

```
\bR\d{2}\b(?!\.\d)
```